# How to get border attribute to fill up 100% width of div having n padding

Tags: html, css

I have made a parent div with 25px padding. In that div, I created another li tag which has a border-top, width is 100% but it doesn't fill up the parent div. It stops at the 25px padding.

Tried border-box but that dint work too.

[image: The Issue]

When I change the width of li element to 115% 
[image: width 115%]

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #17202A;
}

section {
  background-color: #1C2733;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: -0.2px;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  width: 115%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Who to follow</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>dsdfd</li>
    <li>sdfsdf</li>
    <li>sdfsdf</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA6uS.png)

Comment: Can you provide your codes here?

Comment: This is how padding works... you should ditch the padding on the parent and put margin or padding on the heading, and any other elements that should have spacing around them, as appropriate.

Comment: this is the default behavior of padding.

Comment: But wouldnt that be too many padding tags considering the many places I am going to need it?

Comment: @SunnyMahajan what is the solution to this?

Comment: @rohanharikr can u attach your required screenshot aswell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal behaviour for padding. You could remove the padding from the parent element and add it to the child like this:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #17202A;
}

section {
  background-color: #1C2733;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  letter-spacing: -0.2px;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Who to follow</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>dsdfd</li>
    <li>sdfsdf</li>
    <li>sdfsdf</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, but I was wondering why padding:0 !important; is also not working on the li tags

Comment: Your welcome. If you add padding:0 !important to the <li> tags, it will only remove the padding of the <li> tags, not of the parent. Keep in mind, padding is not something that is inherited from a parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 -20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps

1. Remove padding from `section` class.
2. Add padding to `h2` and `li` components.
3. Remove width property of `li`, let it take 100% width by
   default

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}


body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family:Helvetica;
}

.dark{
  background-color: #17202A;
}

section{
  background-color:#1C2733;
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:25px;
  color:white;
}

h1{
  font-size:23px;
  font-weight:800;
  letter-spacing:-0.2px;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul{
  margin-top:20px;
  width:100%;
}

li{
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  align-items:center;
  list-style:none;
  height:50px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  margin:auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body class="dark">
  <section>
    <h1>Who to follow</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>dsdfd</li>
      <li>sdfsdf</li>
      <li>sdfsdf</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #17202A;
}

section {
  background-color: #1C2733;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  letter-spacing: -0.2px;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Who to follow</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>dsdfd</li>
    <li>sdfsdf</li>
    <li>sdfsdf</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that many ways but based your code you do that easily by use negative margin and remove `width` property:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #17202A;
}

section {
  background-color: #1C2733;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: -0.2px;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  padding:10px 20px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left:-20px; /* value equivalent of `padding` left side applied parent container */
  margin-right:-20px; /* value equivalent of `padding` right side applied parent container */
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Who to follow</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>dsdfd</li>
    <li>sdfsdf</li>
    <li>sdfsdf</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 -20px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```